# What does "vialangulo" mean, in the song "Societo de Vivantaj Poetoj"?

Tags: meaning

In the song ["Societo de Vivantaj Poetoj"](http://kantaro.ikso.net/societo_de_vivantaj_poetoj) by La Perdita Generacio, there are the words:

> triangulo
>   ĉiangulo
>   vialangulo

And later:

> triangule
>   ĉiangule
>   vialangule

I know what a *triangulo* is, and assume *ĉiangulo* is "this angle" (though what exactly those words mean together I'm unsure), but what's *vialangulo*? "Your-tongue-person"??

Comment: Any LPG band members on this site who can enlighten us? ;-)

Comment: I just sent the link to Tomas from the PG.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kiam oni diskutas tekstojn de LGP indas scii ke mi ŝatas lirikan ambiguecon. Tio iom kontrastas fundamentan ideon en esperanto — klareco. Mi devas konfesi ke la limo inter la malpreciza kaj la malkomprenebla/sensignifa estas malvasta, kaj ke mi verŝajne stumblis flanken plurfoje.

Pri la teksto de *Societo*.... mi tamen sentas fieron daŭre 11 jarojn poste. :-)

- *vialangulo = ulo vialanga = ulo de via lango = iu kiu havas la econ de via lango*
  (komp. *fremdulo = ulo fremda = iu kiu havas la econ esti fremda*)

Cetere pri *ĉiangulo*: mi celas ke ĝi signifu kaj *ĉi angulo* kaj *ĉio angulo* (laŭ la regulo ke oni libere aŭ tenas aŭ perdas o-finaĵojn en kumetaĵoj.) Per tio mi volas priskribi senton samtempe ĉi tie kaj ĉie.

Mi supozas ke vi notis ke la lasta vorto *eksenlime* ankaŭ estas ambigua.

Comment: Nu, mi ankoraŭ ne scias kio estas la "eco de via lango", sed ĝi ja estas bela kanto :-).

Comment: pri poezio oni foje bezonas tikli sian imagokapablon, cxu ne? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

From reading the poem, these stanzas precede stanzas referring to kissing. So literally it could just mean, as you said, "your tongue person", which I'm guessing translates to "person with your tongue".